# Python proxy - receiving http header from the server

Tags: python, http, proxy, header, http-headers

I'm building a proxy server in Python and I got a question. 
First I'll be showing you a part of my code that presents the receiving data from the client: If there is data from the client, it downloads the content of the requested website (By using the urllib library) and then sending to the client 200 OK with the content length and the content itself:

```
        data = currentSocket.recv(4096)
        if data == "":
            open_client_sockets.remove(currentSocket)
            print 'Conn is closed'
        else:

            dataSplit = data.split("\r\n")
            Host = HostFliter(dataSplit)
            print Host, " Host"
            if Host == "":
                break
            contentURL = urllib.urlopen(Host)
            content_to_send = contentURL.read()
            currentSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length:"+str(len(content_to_send))+"\r\n\r\n"+str(content_to_send))
            contentURL.close()
```

**The variable "Host" contains the url of the website.

Now for the question:
Where do I get the headers from the server and then send them to the client?

**The libraries I use: socket, select, urllib.

**This is for the select library:

`rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([serverSocket] + open_client_sockets, open_client_sockets, [])`

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP response syntax is as follows

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Content-Type: text/html
>   Content-Length: 38
>
> `<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>`

So you need to send headers just before `\r\n` separated by `\n` in above format.